# Normal website optimization

Tags: optimization

I never really put too much time on optimizing website. Sure i put script at the botton, make sprite, get the crap out the HTML and CSS at the end of the contract, event tweek some javascript.

Yesterday, i getting a WordPress site ready to be launch, and delete all the unused plug-in, and getting the one i keep working and up-to-date and i try to benchmark the site just for fun

With this good and right-to-the-point tool : http://gtmetrix.com/ 
here it is i start at 79-80% (yslow and page speed grade).. not bad

with some tweaking and best practice apply (add expire header, gzip, etags, caching, minify) noting a plug-in cannot do... i got to the point where i score 93-94%... a score event a hand coded site cannot get... all with plug-in..

**The question...** all the site is not wp base.. i know.... What is you library, php, script, software to get hat king of speed from a html/javascrip/php website hand coded without too much pain...Something as easy as to download and install a plugin in WP is heaven... what is your tricks ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Moving the static
  content(javascript, css, images) to a
  3rd part hosting, like
  [s3.amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). By this, you won't
  need to worry about CDN and reduce
  the request to your own server.
- Using cache, something like
  [memcached](http://memcached.org/) to reduce the
  data-accessing

Comment: s3.amazon is something we talf about a lot... but it's not free ?

Comment: Frist of all, i am not promoting s3.amazon. Just sharing my experience. It is not free. But, from my experience, it is worth to use rather than hosting static content and worry about CDN. Or you can use other file hosting service. The main goal is reducing requests for static content  to server